# Svn external on external directory

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I have this svn:external file in a project:

```
Silex https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/trunk
Silex/vendor/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit https://github.com/symfony/BrowserKit/trunk
Silex/vendor/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/trunk
Silex/vendor/Symfony/Component/CssSelector https://github.com/symfony/CssSelector/trunk
Silex/vendor/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler/trunk
```

when I do a `svn update` in the external directory I get this svn error: `svn: warning: Unable to lock 'Silex/vendor/Symfony/Component'`

There is a way to checkout an svn:external into a directory owned by another svn:external?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Read the section ["Externals Definition"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) from the SVN Red Book. There you will find the following notice:

> The relative target subdirectories of externals definitions must not
>   already exist on your or other users' systems—Subversion will create
>   them when it checks out the external working copy.

However, it should be possible to use an externals definition like that:

```
 Silex/product https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/trunk
 Silex/vendor/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit https://github.com/symfony/BrowserKit/trunk
 ...
```

So your directories created by `svn:externals` do not exist by the creation of other externals directories.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll want to do is declare the Component externals in the fabpot/Silex/trunk repo instead of this repo.

Comment: the Silex project is hosted in github, not on my local svn server, I cannot modify this...

Comment: I think it may be impossible, based on this tangentially related ticket from svn's tracker:
http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1820